# Save derived class type after casting it to base class

Tags: c++, c++11

**EDIT 2:**

---

Previous solution ("EDIT 1") would not work with `switch`, but I really wanted it to. After some digging around google I discovered [`constexpr` compile time counter](http://b.atch.se/posts/constexpr-counter/) which would allow me to use `switch`. Visual Studio 2015 IDE is not able to determine `constexpr` compile time counter values (yet) and think that they are all the same, however it compiles just fine. My updated solution can be found below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

namespace compileTimeCounter {
    template<int N>
    struct flag {
        friend constexpr int adl_flag(flag<N>);
    };

    template<int N>
    struct writer {
        friend constexpr int adl_flag(flag<N>) {
            return N;
        }

        static constexpr int value = N;
    };

    template<int N, class = char[noexcept(adl_flag(flag<N>())) ? +1 : -1]>
    int constexpr reader(int, flag<N>) {
        return N;
    }

    template<int N>
    int constexpr reader(float, flag<N>, int R = reader(0, flag<N - 1>())) {
        return R;
    }

    int constexpr reader(float, flag<0>) {
        return 0;
    }

    template<int N = 1, int C = reader(0, flag<32>())>
    int constexpr next(int R = writer<C + N>::value) {
        return R;
    }
}

class objectWrapper {
public:
    virtual size_t getType() const noexcept = 0;
};

template<typename T>
class typeWrapper : public objectWrapper {
public:
    static constexpr size_t type = compileTimeCounter::next();
    size_t getType() const noexcept { return this->type; }
};

class classA : public typeWrapper<classA> {
public:
    classA() { std::cout << "classA ctor" << std::endl; }
    ~classA() { std::cout << "classA dtor" << std::endl; }
    void methodA() { std::cout << "methodA called" << std::endl; }
};

class classB : public typeWrapper<classB> {
public:
    classB() { std::cout << "classB ctor" << std::endl; }
    ~classB() { std::cout << "classB dtor" << std::endl; }
    void methodB() { std::cout << "methodB called" << std::endl; }
};

class classC : public typeWrapper<classC> {
public:
    classC() { std::cout << "classC ctor" << std::endl; }
    ~classC() { std::cout << "classC dtor" << std::endl; }
    void methodC() { std::cout << "methodC called" << std::endl; }
};

int main() {
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<objectWrapper>> objects1, objects2;
    objects1.push_back(std::make_shared<classA>());
    objects1.push_back(std::make_shared<classB>());
    objects1.push_back(std::make_shared<classC>());

    objects2 = objects1;

    switch (objects2[0]->getType()) {
        case classA::type:
            reinterpret_cast<classA*>(objects2[0].get())->methodA();
            break;
        case classB::type:
            reinterpret_cast<classB*>(objects2[0].get())->methodB();
            break;
        case classC::type:
            reinterpret_cast<classC*>(objects2[0].get())->methodC();
            break;
    }

    objects2.~vector();
    std::cout << "objects2 destroyed" << std::endl;
    objects1.~vector();
    std::cout << "objects1 destroyed" << std::endl;

    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

---

**EDIT 1:**

---

While Ryan's solution is not bad, I further read about `dynamic_cast` and found out that it might be slow in certain situations. On the other hand, I really like skypjack's solution and updated my code with his (slightly modified it to hide static counter from derived classes).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

template<typename T>
struct typeWrapper;

struct objectWrapper {
    template<typename T>
    friend struct typeWrapper;
private:
    static size_t typeCounter;
public:
    virtual size_t getType() const noexcept = 0;
};

size_t objectWrapper::typeCounter = 0;

template<typename T>
struct typeWrapper : objectWrapper {
    static const size_t type;
    size_t getType() const noexcept { return this->type; }
};

template<typename T>
const size_t typeWrapper<T>::type = objectWrapper::typeCounter++;

class classA : public typeWrapper<classA> {
public:
    classA() { std::cout << "classA ctor" << std::endl; }
    ~classA() { std::cout << "classA dtor" << std::endl; }
    void methodA() { std::cout << "methodA called" << std::endl; }
};

class classB : public typeWrapper<classB> {
public:
    classB() { std::cout << "classB ctor" << std::endl; }
    ~classB() { std::cout << "classB dtor" << std::endl; }
    void methodB() { std::cout << "methodB called" << std::endl; }
};

class classC : public typeWrapper<classC> {
public:
    classC() { std::cout << "classC ctor" << std::endl; }
    ~classC() { std::cout << "classC dtor" << std::endl; }
    void methodC() { std::cout << "methodC called" << std::endl; }
};

int main() {
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<objectWrapper>> objects1, objects2;
    objects1.push_back(std::make_shared<classA>());
    objects1.push_back(std::make_shared<classB>());
    objects1.push_back(std::make_shared<classC>());

    objects2 = objects1;

    if (objects2[0]->getType() == classA::type)
        reinterpret_cast<classA*>(objects2[0].get())->methodA();
    else if (objects2[0]->getType() == classB::type)
        reinterpret_cast<classB*>(objects2[0].get())->methodB();
    else if (objects2[0]->getType() == classC::type)
        reinterpret_cast<classC*>(objects2[0].get())->methodC();

    objects2.~vector();
    std::cout << "objects2 destroyed" << std::endl;
    objects1.~vector();
    std::cout << "objects1 destroyed" << std::endl;

    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

---

I am looking for some way to store different class objects inside `shared_ptr` vector. Now if I store them inside, let's say, `vector<shared_ptr<void>>`, everything is OK, except for the part where I loose my class type and can't cast back.

I have settled on manually saving class type using `enum` and base class (`objectWrapper`). Example is shown below.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>
#include <inttypes.h>

enum class objectType : uint8_t {
    classA,
    classB,
    classC
};

class objectWrapper {
protected:
    objectType type;
    objectWrapper(objectType type) : type(type) {}
public:
    virtual objectType getObjectType() {
        return this->type;
    }
};

class classA : public objectWrapper {
public:
    classA() : objectWrapper(objectType::classA) { 
        std::cout << "classA ctor" << std::endl; 
    }
    ~classA() { std::cout << "classA dtor" << std::endl; }
    void methodA() { std::cout << "methodA called" << std::endl; }
};

class classB : public objectWrapper {
public:
    classB() : objectWrapper(objectType::classB) { 
        std::cout << "classB ctor" << std::endl; 
    }
    ~classB() { std::cout << "classB dtor" << std::endl; }
    void methodB() { std::cout << "methodB called" << std::endl; }
};

class classC : public objectWrapper {
public:
    classC() : objectWrapper(objectType::classC) { 
        std::cout << "classC ctor" << std::endl; 
    }
    ~classC() { std::cout << "classC dtor" << std::endl; }
    void methodC() { std::cout << "methodC called" << std::endl; }
};

int main() {
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<objectWrapper>> objects1, objects2;
    objects1.push_back(std::make_shared<classA>());
    objects1.push_back(std::make_shared<classB>());
    objects1.push_back(std::make_shared<classC>());

    objects2 = objects1;

    switch (objects2[0]->getObjectType()) {
        case objectType::classA:
            dynamic_cast<classA*>(objects2[0].get())->methodA();
            break;
        case objectType::classB:
            dynamic_cast<classB*>(objects2[0].get())->methodB();
            break;
        case objectType::classC:
            dynamic_cast<classC*>(objects2[0].get())->methodC();
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

    objects2.~vector();
    std::cout << "objects2 destroyed" << std::endl;
    objects1.~vector();
    std::cout << "objects1 destroyed" << std::endl;

    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

This way I can create `vector<shared_ptr<objectWrapper>>` and store all my classes and when needed I can cast back to their original types.

While my base class will have some other virtual methods, which I will use instead of casting back to derived type, there will be some exceptions. I will need to cast back to derived class to use some specific methods, but I need to somehow know derived class type before casting to it. I was wondering if there is some easier and cleaner way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another solution would be to use templates and the CRTP idiom:

```
#include<cassert>

struct B {
    static int cnt;
    virtual int type() const noexcept = 0;
};

int B::cnt = 0;

template<typename T>
struct D: B {
    static const int family;
    int type() const noexcept override { return family; }
};

template<typename T>
const int D<T>::family = B::cnt++;

struct A: D<A> { };
struct C: D<C> { };

int main() {
    B *a = new A;
    B *c = new C;
    assert(a->type() != c->type());
    assert(a->type() == A::family);
}
```

Comment: Well... Don't know what to say... Genius idea! I tried something similar, but was not even close to this solution. Now, if you could just add `delete`s at the end it would be perfect.

Answer (score 3):

The most simple way would simply be to dynamically cast the base class to the derived class and check if it succeeded.

For example, instead of using a switch statement with the method `objects2[0]->getObjectType()` in your switch statement, you could put:

```
classA* CA = dynamic_cast<classA*>(objects2[0].get());
if(CA) CA->methodA();

classB* CB = dynamic_cast<classB*>(objects2[0].get());
if(CB) CB->methodB();

classC* CC = dynamic_cast<classC*>(objects2[0].get());
if(CC) CC->methodC();
```

This way your classes don't have to know about their own implementation.

Comment: Did not know `dynamic_cast` would actually return `nullptr` on false casting (did not even expect this). This gives me lots of new possibilities. Will choose your answer later if no one gives better solution.